# Testing an iPad app's speed without an iPad when the simulator runs faster

Tags: performance, ipad, ios-simulator

I have some operations in my iPad app that are CPU-intensive, and I'd really like to be able to test them on the simulator, making sure things will still run smoothly on the actual iPad.

The simulator seems to run faster than the iPad and I need a way to test an iPad app's speed in a more reliable/real-world method.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still hoping to find better answers than this (and happy to switch my "answered" checkmark to a better solution if I see it), but here's how I'm approaching this problem for now:

I'm writing universal apps and testing the CPU-intensive bits on my iPhone.  My thinking is that the iPad's A4 is probably scaled up enough to handle the extra graphics processing that's needed for the larger screen.  So if the same code is smooth on the iPhone, it will probably still be smooth on the iPad.

Comment: iPad A4 runs at 1GHz and has a higher resolution than iPhone 3Gs running at 600Mhz at a lower resolution.
In  my crude tests, iPhone 3Gs and iPad are nearly the same in speed (The larger screen negates the powerful processor and you will notice that significantly when scrolling a tableview will lots of subviews in each cell)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to know how your app will perform on a device is to test it on that device. Apple's apparently given a very small number of developers early access to iPad hardware; if you're not one of them, then you're going to have to wait for April 3 to test it.

Comment: I understand that I can't actually know beyond a doubt how it will run on an iPad until I get one, but I'm will to accept best guesses without having an iPad.  I'm looking for suggestions to perhaps slow my process's use of CPU time, or other methods of predicting how it will run.  Maybe by knowing how my laptop's speed compares to the A4, and measuring my own process's CPU usage - stuff like that.